# Resizing an image in Python using PIL

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to resize an image in Python, and did the following:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('1.jpg')
img.resize((300,200))
img.save('image','jpeg')
```

In the result, the image remains the same size. Why is that? What could I be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: the resized image is called `image` with no file extension.   Because that is the name you gave the file when you saved it.

Comment: run `help(img.save)` to see the documentation on the save method, the first sentence is "Saves this image under the given filename." and in this case the filename you have specified is `'image'`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  Your comments are irrelevant.  It is perfectly fine to have an image file with no extension, and specify the format explicitly, as the OP has done here.

Comment: yes, I hadn't realized that `resize` creates a copy, I was thinking the OP was expecting `1.jpg` to change size but it was saved under a different name but it seems that wasn't the issue at all.

Answer (score 4):

Resize returns a new object, and you didn't assign it to anything.  Use this instead:

```
img = img.resize((300,200))
```